# Is there any way to get an event handler to run directly on UI thread without intermediate threadpool thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, threadpool, dispatcher

I have an event that is fired async via BeginInvoke - so the event handler gets its own threadpool thread.  But all the code in the event handler wants to be dispatched to the UI thread - so the entire event handler code is in a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke block.  This means:

1. Initiating thread fires event with BeginInvoke.
2. A new threadpool thread is created for the event handler code to run on.
3. The event handler immediately just posts its code async to the UI thread using
   the dispatcher (Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...all handler code...).
4. The temp threadpool thread returns quasi immediately - its created only to do a UI thread post.

Is there any way to restructure this to avoid the creation of this very short lived intermediate threadpool thread (I.e so the handler code just runs directly on the UI thread)?

I dont want the event to fire sycnronously (Invoke) - its used in various contexts - and it shouldn't be blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't control the code that fires the event you don't really have a choice; there is no way around the use of the thread pool thread for that short duration.

If you do control the code that fires the event you have the option of ensuring that the event handlers all run in the UI thread.  While this is certainly *possible*, you should think long and hard about whether it should be the case.  For certain event handlers it just makes sense for them to run in the UI thread (as an example, most of the events of `Form` run in the UI thread) and some it doesn't.  If your event is on a UI control it probably makes sense for it to run in the UI thread.  If it's an event of some worker class that you just happen to be using from a UI thread at the moment, it's probably a bad idea to fire the event in the UI thread (as you may, in the future, be using that worker context in a non-WPF context).

If you do want to fire the event in the UI thread it's simple enough.  If you are already in the UI thread when you intend to fire the event just invoke it synchronously:

```
var eventCopy = MyEvent;
if(eventCopy != null) eventCopy();
```

If you're not in the UI thread when you wish to fire the event then marshal to the UI thread before calling the above code:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{ //Or just `Invoke`, if that's appropriate in context
    var eventCopy = MyEvent;
    if(eventCopy != null) eventCopy();
});
```

Based on your edit it seems you want to conditionally fire the event in the UI thread or a thread pool thread based on some specific context, rather than always firing in the UI thread.

While this is possible, you'll need to decide if it's worth it.

As an example you could look at `System.Timers.Timer` which has a `SynchronizingObject` property that allows you to determine how the events are rasied (`null` for the thread pool, or an object capable of marshalling to a particular context in the event of a particular UI model).

You could follow that general pattern.

There are a number of specific methods.  You could capture the value in `SynchronizationContext.Current` at the time your worker thread was first created, and use that (possibly with a boolean value to disable capturing the source sync context if you might need to disable it, or forcably enable it).

Another option is to just have a property that accepts a `SynchronizationContext`, or some other mechanism of marshalling code to a given context (you could invent your own, use delegates, etc.).

Comment: That confirms what I suspected.  The event is on a worker class and it does not make sense to always invoke on UI (this case is a particular use of the event in a UI app, but thats not generally the case).  So the short answer is "there is no way around the use of threadpool for that short duration".

Comment: Ok - edit understood - thanks - at this point not worth doing that - but I think what your suggesting is the "correct" solution (to handle both contexts).

Answer (score 4):

Can you just call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` directly instead of using a threadpool thread?

Comment: No - in the event handler where I call Dispatcher.BeginInvoke Im already in a threadpool thread (from event being fired async myevent.BeginInvoke).  To clarify Im note explicity using a threadpool thread - that just what the event handler is running in because the event is fired async with BeginInvoke.

Comment: Right, but in step 1, can the initiating thread just call `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` directly instead of initiating this threadpool thread?

Comment: Initiating thread is in a library.  It doesnt know anything about the handler (which in one case is posted to UI but in other cases not).

Comment: You might be out of luck then, if the initiating thread is in a library and it is making your requests on the thread pool. Unless there is a way to either modify that portion of the library or ask it to initiate the event in a different way...